# upnp:rootdevice vs. pnp:rootdevice and Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, upnp, ssdp

I have been working on some SSDP code to publish and discover devices. I notice that Windows Explorer (under Windows 8 go to 'Network' node in folders list, right click and choose refresh) explicitly searches for "pnp:rootdevice". I cannot find this exact device type listed in any of the UPnP specification documents I've found (mostly I'm using for http://www.upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf reference). The specifications I've seen all talk about "upnp:rootdevice".

Given there is a single character difference, and I can't find any reference to "pnp:rootdevice" I am wondering if this is a bug/typo in the Windows system (seems unlikely), is from an earlier/alternate protocol, or meets some other standard I haven't found. It seems it must be a known thing as devices on my network respond to that device type in a search request, but  can't find any reference to it in the standards.

Does anyone know why Windows Explorer uses pnp:rootdevice not upnp:rootdevice and if there is any real difference between them? Does anyone have a link to accurate information explaining the differences/when to use one vs the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I'm late to the party but it seems that Windows Explorer is not adhering to the standards.
I just found this out on this link: http://yortw.github.io/RSSDP/api/Rssdp.Infrastructure.SsdpDevicePublisherBase.SupportPnpRootDevice.html#Rssdp_Infrastructure_SsdpDevicePublisherBase_SupportPnpRootDevice I found it while trying to get my device to show up, but it doesn't show even with the correct device type.